# Quelle est la forme verbale dans "disposes-en" ?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison

L'écriture de "disposes-en" se trouve assez couramment dans la littérature, par exemple dans la [Prière de Saint Ignace de Loyola](https://intranet.cvxfrance.com/2015/05/13/la-priere-de-saint-ignace/):

"*Disposes-en selon ton entière volonté.*".

Quels sont le temps et le mode verbaux du verbe *disposer* dans cette phrase ? Les seules occurrences de la forme "disposes" dans la conjugaison sont la deuxième personne du singulier du présent de l'indicatif et du présent du subjonctif; néanmoins aucun de ces deux cas ne semble approprié à la phrase en question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est de l'impératif.

L'impératif seul ne prend généralement pas de "s", mais quand il est suivi par "en" ou "y" on en rajoute un si la prononciation le nécessite.

On dit

> Va, donne, pense.

Mais

> Vas-y, donnes-en, penses-y.